# SQL Server: how to get statistics sizes?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'd like to query the sizes of all results created by `CREATE STATISTICS`: the histograms and the density vectors.

I tried the following snippet:

```
SELECT
    t.Name AS TableName,
    p.rows AS RowCounts,
    CAST(ROUND((SUM(a.used_pages) / 128.00), 2) AS NUMERIC(36, 2)) AS Used_MB,
    CAST(ROUND((SUM(a.total_pages) - SUM(a.used_pages)) / 128.00, 2) AS NUMERIC(36, 2)) AS Unused_MB,
    CAST(ROUND((SUM(a.total_pages) / 128.00), 2) AS NUMERIC(36, 2)) AS Total_MB
FROM 
    sys.stats t
INNER JOIN 
    sys.partitions p ON t.object_id = p.OBJECT_ID --AND i.index_id = p.index_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.allocation_units a ON p.partition_id = a.container_id
GROUP BY 
    t.Name, p.Rows
ORDER BY 
    t.Name;
```

However the returned results under "Used_MB" obviously contains the original table size.

Any way to quickly obtain *just* the stats sizes?

Comment: Dunno why you would need this or care about it but probably need to do something based off this. https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/27171/3690

Comment: A quick reply, I'm pretty sure I once read that any given set of statistics (for a column or for an index) is stored in one page (8k).

Comment: Even for incremental statistics on partitioned tables, the size occupied by stats histograms is absolutely negligible compared to the data, so it's not clear why this would be of any use. Note that increasing the sample size will improve the *quality* of the statistics (and the time needed to generate them), but will not measurably increase the *size* -- no more than 200 histogram steps are ever present. Maybe if you needed to account for every last allocated byte...

Comment: I can see the 200 bins would amount to maybe about 16*200 bytes.  What about the "density vectors", what exactly are stored in those - is it just one number, the average density, per (col1, ..., col K) combo?

Comment: Basically, yes, so even smaller than the histograms.